# on a book due to be published in 2020

Tags: prepositions

*In 2016, Forbes Magazine named her one of their 30 under 30 in media and she was working on a **book due to be published in 2020**.*

https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/breaking-lyra-mckee-shooting-two-14436462

Do you think that the preposition "due" is necessary? Would it not be sufficient just: "… on a book to be published…"?

Comment: "Due to be" refers to something planned; "to be" alone refers to something destined, and often known after the event. I am due to be promoted on June 1st; John was a happy boy. He was to be unhappy in adulthood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can omit "due" in this case but then you'll lose some extra meaning.

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/due) :

***Due***

Adjective

: Expected at or planned for at a certain time.

with infinitive

‘talks are due to adjourn tomorrow’

When you use only the Infinitive after a noun, you just indicate its function or purpose.

Though in your sentence there is a future time indication (in 2020), so omitting "due" is not so essential.